# How to enable content-range download in nodejs and nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

My work flow is:

```
Client --> nginx--> nodejs
```

Client calls RestAPI to download a file. RestAPI has authentication information which should be authenticated before downloading requested file. nginx redirects RestAPI to nodejs, nodejs authenticates theninfo and asks nginx back to continue download. I implemented above flow successfully. Following piece of nodejs code to download file.

```
      res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/octet-stream');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
      res.header('X-Accel-Redirect',partialDirPath + filename);
      res.end();
```

My Problem is, how to improve above code to allow Content-Range (byte range) based download.

curl command downloads complete package file on my setup. whereas I expect, it show download only 2 bytes.

```
curl -r 1-2 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"license":"license","type":"type1"}' 'http://nginx-server/dlr/package'
```

Could you please help me to figure out what things should I change either in nginx config  or node js code so that only specified bytes range can be downloaded?

Thanks